# Apply Sphinx4 to voice data recorded in Android Phone

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

This sounds weird. But, I would like to analyze byte data recorded in my Android phone by Sphinx4. And, no good result. I know this would come from my configuration problem.
I would like to hear some idea if you have experience about Sphinx4 & same experience.

I would like describe my environment:

1. Phone (Android, Nexsus One)

   - sampling rate = 8000
   - audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
   - channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
2. Sphinx4

   - sampleRate = 16000
   - bigEndianData = false
   - using streamDataSource

So, I recorde voice data (byte[]) and then, analyze it by Sphinx4.
The following is an example voice (one two three) recorded by my phone.

```
-29:-1:84:0:-77:0:-88:0:-88:0:-99:0:-105:0:-82:0:-88:0:-99:0:101:0:89:0:118:0:95:0:44:0:22:0:28:0:39:0:56:0:50:0:28:0:22:0:-6:-1:-17:-1:-6:-1:-34:-1:-34:-1:-85:-1:-85:-1:-79:-1:115:-1:126:-1:-113:-1:-85:-1:-102:-1:104:-1:115:-1:121:-1:-102:-1:-113:-1:-96:-1:-57:-1:-96:-1:109:-1:104:-1:-79:-1:16:0:101:0:-105:0:-122:0:-122:0:-99:0:67:0:101:0:78:0:-6:-1:11:0:-6:-1:39:0:50:0:56:0:22:0:0:0:101:0:123:0:33:0:118:0:56:0:-40:-1:84:0:-85:-1:87:-1:76:-1:-54:-2:31:-1:31:-1:70:-1:0:0:-17:-1:-68:-1:56:0:50:0:-102:-1:-12:-1:-113:-1:-124:-1:-6:-1:11:0:106:0:101:0:50:0:-124:-1:104:-1:-102:-1:126:-1:81:-1:76:-1:-34:-1:-6:-1:44:0:-105:0:-110:0:78:0:67:0:-68:-1:-45:-1:33:0:-74:-1:-57:-1:-57:-1:33:0:28:0:39:0:-45:-1:5:0:25:1:123:0:-62:-1:-110:0:118:0:73:0:-93:0:73:0:16:0:-40:-1:-119:-1:-68:-1:101:0:61:0:-12:-1:-88:0:70:1:-48:0:-65:0:25:1:56:0:-34:-1:0:0:28:0:106:0:-127:0:-77:0:123:0:-68:-1:-29:-1:61:0:-12:-1:5:0:22:0:-79:-1:-96:-1:-102:-1:31:-1:70:-1:-96:-1:-79:-1:-107:-1:-96:-1:-51:-1:-107:-1:121:-1:-96:-1:-96:-1:104:-1:109:-1:81:-1:-79:-1:33:0:28:0:22:0:39:0:44:0:73:0:67:0:118:0:95:0:-17:-1:-17:-1:-113:-1:-57:-1:-107:-1:31:-1:98:-1:-124:-1:-29:-1:-57:-1:-79:-1:-45:-1:-62:-1:-12:-1:-85:-1:-34:-1:33:0:-51:-1:-102:-1:109:-1:-85:-1:109:-1:25:-1:115:-1:92:-1:109:-1:87:-1:25:-1:121:-1:-85:-1:92:-1:-85:-1:0:0:-6:-1:-29:-1:-119:-1:-62:-1:22:0:95:0:84:0:33:0:-122:0:-93:0:-99:0:-122:0:11:0:-40:-1:-51:-1:-79:-1:-12:-1:-23:-1:-45:-1:-34:-1:-12:-1:-34:-1:-23:-1:22:0:16:0:56:0:67:0:-34:-1:-102:-1:-113:-1:-107:-1:121:-1:-102:-1:11:0:39:0:28:0:11:0:89:0:95:0:123:0:-105:0:28:0:16:0:-45:-1:-85:-1:-6:-1:44:0
```

Each byte data is separated by ":".

Answer (score 0):

If you record at 8000 on android, sphinx4 sample rate must be 8000 Hz too. You also need to use 8khz model from sphinx4 distribution or any other 8khz model and you need ot set filterbank parameters (upper frequency and so on) according to documentation

[Using Sphinxtrain models in sphinx4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/UsingSphinxTrainModels.html)

For example of properly configured 8khz input see `sphinx4/test/performance/wsj_8khz/config.xml`

Alternatively, record on Android at 16000 Hz by setting proper AudioRecorder parameter. That will improve the accuracy of the decoding.

Comment: I see.I'll try your suggestions. Thank you every time.

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question. Actually, I downloaded sphinx4-1.0beta6-src where I could get "test/performance/wsj_8khz/config.xml". But, they are using some models which are not contained that package. Where can I get that??? I cannot find that. For example, in "dictionary" configuration, "/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_8kHz_31mel_200Hz_3500Hz/dict/fillerdict" is used. But, in that package, I can find "models/acoustic/wsj_8kHz/", but no   file or directory of "fillerdict".

Comment: Config file is in sources, look better. Fillerdict is now called noisedict. The path in dictionary configuration is the path inside jar, not the path in filesystem. You can use the path in filesystem if needed.